# flock: bad number: myfile.lock

Tags: linux, bash, slackware

I try to put a lock on a file like this:

```
flock -e myfile.lock
```

The result is:

```
flock: bad number: myfile.lock
```

Doesn't matter whether file exist or not, or whether I'm root. I even tried chmod a+rwx myfile. Still get the same error. I tried the same not on my machine but on Debian and I get the same error...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command is missing. Try:

```
flock -e myfile.lock ls
```

The number is the file descriptor of the usage alternativ:

```
(
  flock -e 200
  ls
) 200>myfile.lock
```

See the man page.

Comment: thanks, the number part I still dont get, but the missing command tip worked here: terminal 1 `flock -x ./test.txt sleep 10`, and after at terminal 2 `flock -x ./test.txt ls`

Comment: Why is the command `ls` necessary?

Comment: @Viesturs It is just a placeholder for anything you want to execute with the lock.